# How to detect changes in textarea by comparing new value with current datastore value

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm using Jinja2 and Google App Engine.

My model:

```
class TestModel(db.Model):
    value = db.TextProperty()
    id = db.IntegerProperty()
```

A class for editing the value:

```
class Edit(Handler):
    def get(self):
        #show textarea with current value, let user edit value


    def post(self):
        #get new textarea value, filter database for model instance BY ID and replace with new value
```

In the post method, I only replace the value if it is different from the current datastore value.
So I retrieve the current value in the datastore and compare it to the newvalue:

```
test = TestModel.all().filter("id", id).get()
current = test.value

newvalue = self.request.get('newvalue')

if newvalue != current:
    change = True
else:
    change = False
```

and I only commit the newvalue if if `change` is `True`. However, when I run the code, change is False even if I make edits in the textarea. Why is the code interpreting `newvalue` and `current` as the same thing?

Comment: Are you sure that `current` and `newvalue` are really different? If they were the same string,  `change` would be definitely `False`. Try printing out them right before the `if`.

Comment: Yes, the logs show they are the same. I'm using `<textarea type="text" name="note" class = "textarea" value = "{{note}}" cols="50" rows="10">{{note | safe}}</textarea>` if that makes a difference, where note is the value attribute for testmodel

Comment: In order to retrieve the relevant value you can write `test = TestModel.get_by_id(id)`. all() retrieves all entries of TestModel when you are looking only for one.